# Filter from Fusion Table to Google Maps v3 Checkbox Issues

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3, checkbox, where-clause, google-fusion-tables

Rather than use a million kmls (which would have stopped displaying after ten or so) I've tried to take a Fusion table and use checkboxes to toggle between different filters. This worked pretty well for the first two, but now the other categories won't show unless the first one or two are clicked and clicked off. Clearly something is amiss. I stole the code from the Google example (IN, about pizza shops) but this hasn't worked on expansion. Also, I've got an expanding sidebar, which isn't helping me keep this under control.

I've created a bunch of these:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Food Manufacturing/Wholesale'),
        'click', function() {
          filterMap(layer, tableId, map);
    });
```

And then later this:

```
      function filterMap(layer, tableId, map) {
    var where = generateWhere();

    if (where) {
      if (!layer.getMap()) {
        layer.setMap(map);
      }
      layer.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: 'Longitude',
          from: tableId,
          where: where
        }
      });
    } else {
      layer.setMap(null);
    }
  }

  // Generate a where clause from the checkboxes. If no boxes
  // are checked, return an empty string.
  function generateWhere() {
    var filter = [];
    var stores = document.getElementsByName('store');
    for (var i = 0, store; store = stores[i]; i++) {
      if (store.checked) {
        var storeName = store.value.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');
        filter.push("'" + storeName + "'");
      }
    }
    var where = '';
    if (filter.length) {
      where = "'Displ_Type' IN (" + filter.join(',') + ')';
    }
    return where;
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

And then these in a div body:

```
<li><a1><input type="checkbox" name="store" id="cafe" value="Cafe">Cafe</a1></li>
    <li><a1><input type="checkbox" name="store" id="Catering" value="Catering"> Catering</a1></li>
    <li><a1><input type="checkbox" name="store" id="Cooking School" value="Cooking School"> Cooking School</a1></li>
```

Also
http://jsfiddle.net/pwhqq/1/

The Fusion table is:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S7955100ZHL

Answer (score 0):

Annnnnd I'm an idiot. The solution is not to name your Fusion Table columns (which will become your ids and your names and your values) anything with capital letters or spaces or punctuation marks. Java does not take kindly to it.